Is a linear order dense if and only if its covering relation is empty?
For a linear (or even partial) order $(L,\leq)$, the covering relation $R$ on $L$ is the binary relation that holds between $x$ and $y$ if and only if $x<y$, but there is no $z \in L$ such that $x<z<y$. Is it the case that for a linear order $L$, $L$ is densely ordered if and only if the covering relation $R$ of $L$ is empty? If not, does at least one direction of the implication hold, and if so, which direction?

A linear order is dense iff its covering relation is empty.
($\impliedby$) If the covering relation of a linear order is empty, then for any $x, y$ such that $x < y$ then $\neg x R y$ so there is a $z \in L$ with $x < z < y$ by the definition of covering. Therefore the order is dense.
($\implies$) Conversely, in a dense order, for any $x, y$ with $x<y$ there is a $z \in L$ with $x < z < y$ by the definition of density. So $\neg xRy$. (And if $x \not< y$ then $\neg x Ry$ also.)
